# VS2017 not showing MVC Controller with view using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I created a normal ASP.NET web application and adding MVC to it manually as I think this is the best way to learn MVC design pattern.

I have created a model and now I am trying to create the controller for that model by right-clicking in the `Controller` folder > Add > Controller however, not seeing option for "MVC Controller with Views using Entity Framework".

Here's what I have already done:

1. Added NuGet Package in my solution
2. Searched other questions that may help but none did.

**UPDATE WITH MORE INFORMATION:**

The Nuget package I have installed is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`. The problem is that I need to add MVC Controller with views using Entity Framework however, it's not in the list of Controller's folder > Add > Controller

Comment: How did you create `asp.net web application`? Do you develop with asp.net or asp.net core?

Comment: I developed it with ASP.NET Core

Comment: Could you share us detail steps including creating mvc template?

Answer (score 12):

I run into same issue today and the way to fix it was to simply:

move / delete **Pages** folder from project main directory.

Once you remove the folder you can scaffold the controller with "MVC Controller with view using Entity Framework" option again.
This issue was reported a while ago and was [supposed to be fixed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/431328/scaffolding-error-there-are-no-scaffolders-support.html?childToView=558097#comment-558097) but seems to still occur as **end of May 2019**

Comment: Still an issue as of today

Comment: Same problem in VS Community 2019 16.4.3. After moving Pages to a sub folder, I now have the scaffolding option for EF actions.

Comment: @scx I don't have "Pages Folder" in my project!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit weird.

When you right click on the Controller folder, then choose Add New Item, you won't see MVC Controller with view using Entity Framework in the list

But when you choose Controller from the context menu.

You'll see MVC Controller with view using Entity Framework in the list

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder named Backup in the root directory and moved the Pages folder into it as answered by "scx". Then when I click on the Controller folder-> New Scaffolded Item, it shows the option MVC with Views using EntityFramework. I am using VS2019

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015, right-click the folder (for example: Controller folder), then click:
"Add" --> "New Scaffolded Item..."

After that, the "Add scaffold" window will appear.
The following items will be listed there:

- MVC 5 Controller - Empty
- MVC 5 Controller with read/write actions
- MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework

Comment: How useful is it to add an answer based on Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Because, I was going through the same problem; And it could be very useful to other Visual Studio 2015 users as well;
And I think this applies to both versions. Sometimes its difficult to find an aswer to especific version. So, why not try something that works to other version? In my case it worked.
Sorry about my english.. I'm not fluent.

Comment: Well, the thing is, it seems to be a VS2017-specific issue. It doesn't help to know that it works in other versions.

Comment: No It´s not.. This issue happens with VS2015 too... The answer provided by @Jon, give-me a insight how to deal with this. And again, if someone like me, With this same doubt, read this page. It will help this person to solve its problem. I'm using VS2015 and this actions definily help me a lot.